# ApiPlatform: security on subresource routes

Tags: php, security, api-platform.com, symfony6

I'm ugrading my back-end from APIPlateform 2.6 to 3.1.
I have a problem to configure security on subresource and i don't find any documentation about that.

Below, an example of a subresource declaration:

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/parent-entities/{id}/sub-entities.{_format}',
    operations: [new GetCollection()],
    uriVariables: [
        'id' => new Link(
            fromClass: SubEntityClass::class,
            toClass: ParentEntityClass::class,
            identifiers: ['parentEntity']
        ),
    ],
    security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_USER\')'
)]
```

The security current security annotation is working fine, but i want to ensure that the user can access to the parent-entity resource with id {id}.

I already have a specific voter for the ParentEntity class.

Now, i want to add security like that, but it does not work :

`security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_USER\')  AND is_granted("VIEW", object.getParentEntity())'`

or

`security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_USER\')  AND is_granted("VIEW", object)'`

I want to return 403 if user don't have access to parentEntity resource.

Someone have an idea?

A solution, is to don't use subresource and use

1. add API Filter on parentEntity property in SubEntity

```
    #[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['parentEntity.id' => 'exact'])]
    private ParentEntity $parentEntity;
```

2. URL is : `/sub-entities?parent-entity={id}`
3. Add a State Provider, and programmatically check security...

```
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $parentEntityIds = $context['filters']['parentEntity'] ?? [];
        
        // ...
            if (!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('VIEW', $parentEntity)) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException('Access Denied.');
            }
        // ...
    }
```

I have a lot of subresources and don't want to implement all thats things...

Thank you all,

Manu.

Comment: What about create a voter and check if `object.getParentEntity()` is granted in it? You could register all your entities like this: `$parent = match (true) {$subject instanceof MyObject => $subject->getParentEntity()}; $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('VIEW', $parent);`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Api-platform does not provide a straightforward way to check security based on a parent entity in a manyToOne relationship with the standard voters.

It is possible to use the uriVariable as a subject in the voter though.
Define your ApiResource like this:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/parent_entities/{id}/children.{_format}',
    operations: [new GetCollection()],
    uriVariables: [
        'id' => new Link(
            toProperty: 'parent',
            fromClass: ParentEntity::class, identifiers: ['id']
        )
    ],
    security: 'is_granted("VIEW_BY_ID", id)'
)]
```

and in your voter you can check it by searching your parent entity with the "id" subject:

```php
$parent = $this->em->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $subject]);
$user = $token->getUser();
return $user !== null && $parent->getOwner()->getId() === $user->getId();
```